# How do I set file timesamps in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file, timestamp

I need to update file timestamps (namely `st_ctime`, `st_atime`, `st_mtime`) of an existing file in a C program.

On Win32, I could use [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to update the timestamps.

How do I achieve the same on Linux?

---

**Edit**
I know `touch` but since I've put a `C` tag to the question, I hoped that I could do it with a system call instead of calling an external command...

Comment: something like `system ("touch <filename>")` ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: oh C'Mon! I'm trying to write serious code, no hacking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can change the creation time of a file but you can use the [utime](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=utime) function to change the access and modified times.

Comment: `st_ctime` is status change time, not creation time. Actually, in the normal filesystems used by Linux, such as ext3/ext4, as far as I know, the filesystem does not store the file creation time.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`utimensat` or `futimens`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html):

```
int utimensat(int dirfd, const char *pathname,
    const struct timespec times[2], int flags);

int futimens(int fd, const struct timespec times[2]);
```

> utimensat, futimens - change file timestamps with nanosecond precision